# Excel solver in R

Tags: r, excel, search, package, solver

I have been trying to find something similar to excel solver in `r`.

For example I have the following program:

```
L=2.4
UCL=L; LCL=-L
ARL=1/(pnorm(LCL, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE)+pnorm(UCL, mean = 0, 
sd = 1, lower.tail = FALSE))
```

I want `r` to search for a value of "L" such that my resultant "ARL" is close to e.g. 200.

Is there a way to do so in r?

Comment: arent you basically looking for an L value that gives the area under a standard normal curve = 0.0025?

Comment: Yes I am. In this simple case, I can easily go to normal curve and find the quantile but I want r to try different values and give me the resultant "L" that gives me "ARL" e.g. within (199.9,200.1). The way Excel solver does. I am looking to solve some complex problems which are not straight forward standard normal quantile points.

Comment: then use `qnorm`

Comment: qnorm wont work for what I am looking for. I have a complex problem which doesnt converge to standard normal percentile. I want r to do something like optimization and search for all possible "L" values that yield "ARL" 200.

Comment: You can most likely and easily search using a golden section search algorithm. Not sure if R has some builtin functions to perform the search.

Comment: see help("solve") which you should be able to find using google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f <- function(L) {
  UCL=L; LCL=-L
  ARL=1/(pnorm(LCL, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE)+pnorm(UCL, mean = 0, 
                                                               sd = 1, lower.tail = FALSE))
  ARL-200
}

uniroot(f,c(1,10))
```

It will return

```
$root
[1] 2.807

$f.root
[1] -0.0003725

$iter
[1] 13

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.532e-05
```

So the solution is L=2.807 and it took 13 iterations.

Comment: Thank you Erwin Kalvelagen.